how can I programmatically with java, from my app itself, get the namespace my app belongs on kubernetes?
My app is running on kubernetes and I need to get the namespace my app is running.
 The problem is, that the same app could run in two different clusters dev or prod.
My java health app could run either on dev or prod cluster. So I need to somehow to find out the namespace without knowing on which cluster it runs.
 I’m new in this and would like some help.
Thank you in advance.

Does this answer your question? How to get current namespace from running pod usin client api

You can expose pod information to containers through environment variables
In your case, add to env of you container:
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace

and then, MY_POD_NAMESPACE env variable will be accessible to your application.

Hello Andrew,
Thank you for your reply.
Maybe I didn't describe my problem properly.
My java health app could run either on dev or prod cluster.
So I need to somehow to find out the namespace without knowing on which cluster it runs.
e.g. dev namespace == namespace-devl for dev cluster
prod namespace ==  namespace-prod for prod cluster
Hope this helps

My answer gives you exactly that - a way to get a namespace name into env variable. So when your application is running in dev cluster - MY_POD_NAMESPACE would return namespace-devl, and in port MY_POD_NAMESPACE would return namespace-prod. You can use System.getenv("MY_POD_NAMESPACE") to get this value inside your java code
